# Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '1000' reached, aborting!

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I get this error on every page if I disable a product while it's in a cart. Only way to fix it is to clear browser cache and cookies.

I know there are already a lot of answers about this saying to increase `xdebug.max_nesting_level` in php.ini, but I don't have anything xdebug related in php.ini.

```
vagrant@penn:~$ php -v
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 (cli) (built: Oct 28 2015 01:34:46) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans
```

What should I do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Run a phpinfo.php `<?php phpinfo() ?>` from your browser and show the result please.

Comment: @JonathanRibas I added screenshots of xdebug from phpinfo().

Comment: On your phpinfo can you see a xdebug.ini or just php.ini? On your server find  `xdebug` word inside those `.ini` files.

Comment: @JonathanRibas I can see  /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini.

Comment: Change the `xdebug.max_nesting_level` to a bigger value then restart your php-fpm and Apache or Nginx.

Comment: @JonathanRibas I increased it to 30000 and now it just shows 502 Bad Gateway error. I guess it worked?

Comment: You site is running?

Comment: @JonathanRibas yes

Comment: I've posted my comments as an answer, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1/** Run a phpinfo.php `<?php phpinfo() ?>` from your browser.

**2/** Search for the word `xdebug`, if you find it, it means xdebug is installed correctly on your PHP version.

**3/** Search for `xdebug.ini` or `php.ini`

**4/** Edit your `.ini` file increasing `xdebug.max_nesting_level` value.

**5/** Restart your php-fpm and Apache or Nginx.